# How to resize images from my dataset(64,64) to fit VGG16(224,224)

Tags: keras, deep-learning

VGG16 takes (224,224) size images as its input.
I have a  **.h5 file** which i want to test in this model.
Problem is images in my dataset are **(64,64)**.
My file is **test_catvnoncat.h5**

1.How to change my entire .h5 images to (224,224)

thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use OpenCV's `resize` function:

```py
resized = cv2.resize(img, (224, 224))
```

You can look at the doc [here](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html#resize)

Comment: @ShivVratPandey You can either load your dataset, transform it and save it, or just load it and transform it before passing it to VGG